# itemindent and nested lists

Tags: lists, indentation

LaTeX lists are good and bad. They make life much simpler when it comes to left and right margins and vertical spacing. But they do have quirks.

In the following MWE, I have two simple list environments: `lista` and `listb`. I'd like `lista` to have indented paragraphs. and `listb` not to have indented paragraphs. The set up works fine except if `listb` is the first paragraph in `lista`. In this case, `listb` begins with an indent thanks to the `\itemindent` setting in `lista`.

What options do I have to modify `lista` and/or `listb` to get consistent behaviour of `listb` within `lista` regardless of whether it is the first paragraph or a subsequent paragraph?

The best I have been able to come up with so far is adding something like this to argument `#2` of `\list` in environment `listb`:

```
\if@newlist
  \if@minipagefalse
    \leavevmode
    \vspace{\glueexpr -\baselineskip - \parskip}%
  \fi
  \topsep 0pt
\else
  \topsep \listbdefaulttopsep
\fi
```

but it seems a bit clunky to me and also involves potentially re-adjusting `\topsep` before the end of the list. I'm also worries that this code isn't robust enough and will fail in too many unexpected circumstances.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{lista}{%
  \list{}{%
    \topsep 0pt
    \partopsep 0pt
    \leftmargin 0pt
    \rightmargin 0pt
    \itemindent 1.333em
    \listparindent 1.333em
    \labelsep 0pt
    \parsep 0pt
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{listb}{%
  \list{}{%
    \topsep 0pt
    \partopsep 0pt
    \leftmargin 3em
    \rightmargin 3em
    \itemindent 0pt
    \listparindent 0pt
    \labelsep 0pt
    \parsep 0pt
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lista}
  \textbf{Keep first line indent here.}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{listb}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{listb}
\end{lista}

\bigskip

\begin{lista}
  \begin{listb}
    \textbf{Remove first line indent here.}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{listb}
\end{lista}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Comment: Why in the second case you insert `listb` into `lista`? Just insert only `listab` in text. Is there some special reason that you not do s?

Comment: @Zarko The same reason you might nest any list, e.g., `enumerate` in `quote`. Obviously the example is minimal and not real world.

Comment: @Zarko, in fact the same behaviour is observed if you put `enumerate` inside `quotation`. Sure, the answer could be "Don't ever put `enumerate` as the first thing inside a `quotation` environment. But perhaps there are other answers.

Comment: Is acceptable that you write your list on the following way: `\begin{lista}\textbf{Keep first line indent here.}
  \lipsum[1][1-4]
    \begin{listb}
        \lipsum[2][1-3]
    \end{listb}
\end{lista}

\begin{lista}~
    \begin{listb}\textbf{Remove first line indent here.}
        \lipsum[2][1-3]
    \end{listb}
\end{lista}` ? Observe inserted ~after `\begin{lista}` in the second case.

Comment: @Zarko, no. It's for a style file and I'd like to keep standard syntax. Both `lista` and `listb` can have optional arguments too.

Comment: Mmm...`\AddToHook{env/listb/before}{\leavevmode\vspace{-\parsep}}` can solve the specific problem.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL, the hook is unnecessary, since I can modify `lisb` directly and this doesn't work at all. `\parsep` is 0pt at this point so your `\vspace` does nothing. Plus as soon as you put `\leavevmode` in, there is extra space inserted above the list. I already can do this kind of thing in a more sophisticated way using the code outlined as my best option.

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, I understand, but you don't have much escape from this by starting the first `lista` environment and immediately starting `listb`, I have tried to get around the same problem with a project (https://gist.github.com/pablgonz/cce28f4d19e4288d2fdb7314461ba691), but when starting the nested environment, the `\parsep` parameters of the nested environment, `\baslineskip` added to the `\topsep` value of the current list are a headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `\ifvmode` that you're not in a paragraph, and then force horizontal mode with `\noindent` before `listb`. But this generates a vertical `\baselineskip` which should be canceled.

```tex
\ifvmode\noindent\vspace{-\baselineskip}\fi
```

Full example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{lista}{%
  \list{}{%
    \topsep 0pt
    \partopsep 0pt
    \leftmargin 0pt
    \rightmargin 0pt
    \itemindent 1.333em
    \listparindent 1.333em
    \labelsep 0pt
    \parsep 0pt
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{listb}{%
  \ifvmode\noindent\vspace{-\baselineskip}\fi
  \list{}{%
    \topsep 0pt
    \partopsep 0pt
    \leftmargin 3em
    \rightmargin 3em
    \itemindent 0pt
    \listparindent 0pt
    \labelsep 0pt
    \parsep 0pt
  }%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lista}
  \textbf{Keep first line indent here.}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{listb}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{listb}
\end{lista}

\bigskip

\begin{lista}
  \begin{listb}
    \textbf{Remove first line indent here.}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{listb}
\end{lista}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\noindent\vspace{-\baselineskip}` is now inserted at start of each `lisb` created in vertical mode, even if `listb` is not the first material in `lista` (eg. if you add a line break before `lisb`). But I don't think it will be a problem.